# Javascript assignment operator is not working

Tags: javascript, ecma262

log.original_fields is always null. why?

```
var updateChangeLog = function(log, currentRecord) {
   var records, record;
   if(!log.original_fields) {
      records = ["a","b"];
      log["original_fields"] = records;   
      // log.original_fields = records; // doesnt work either
      debugger;
   }
}
```

Comment: what are you passing to the `updateChangeLog` function? Is `log` an object?

Comment: Yeah, you must be setting something up wrong, works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/AMnNx/

Comment: its letting me alter new properties but i can't do anything with existing properties. the object is a record coming out of web sql. http://i1120.photobucket.com/albums/l493/powerfulcrunch/wth.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't thin it's good practice to modify an object the function recieves as a param, at least without then returning the object.  Better way would be make the function a method of the log object.

like logObject.updateChangeLog(currentRecord);

the updateChangeLog would containt
...
if(!self.original_fields)
self.original_fields = records;
...
but remember to initialize the logObject original_fields to false or nil.

Comment: i think what you are talking about is right. maybe it doesn't let you change the object up the stack so you don't mess up something lower on the stack/something to do with asychronous calls. either way, cloning log at the start of the function solved the problem. return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(object))